# Imagemagick class "imagick" not found in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working on `cakephp` project which I need to run sample source code before I started my project.

I have config all file in `apache` and `PHP` and my project seem to be run well, but one problem that I faced is about class `imagick` not found.

Comment: Congratulations, you found an error! However, what is your question? Where is your code? Please read the [faq] and add relevant information to your question, in its current format, this question is not suitable for StackOverflow to be answered

Comment: My code is not errors. I said it has problem with class "not" found. I just need the guild how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you don't have imagick installed on your sever

Comment: But I already installed it. I think I missed some some step of install or config it, so can you tell me how to install and config it.